# Multiple data uri pdf files into 1 file javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, data-uri

I have a working file system to save PDF files.  At the end of the job, I want to be able to take all these PDF files and combine them into 1 file (one page after another).  When I download the file off of the file system, I get the data uri.  I can call window.open(data uri) and it will open the pdf.  I have tried to take 2 data uri strings and simply combine them but it doesn't open anything.

```
data:application/pdf;base64,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...
```

How can I combine these data strings to get one page after another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open 2 pdfs files in a new window, an alternative to that you can try one of the pdf libraries for javascript to merge the pdf files and then open the newly created merged pef file in the new window. I recommend you this [library PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/)

Another option is send files to your web service process in backend and return the fileuri to client of the merged file.

Comment: You are the man! I have made a server function to use the npm package easy-pdf-merge and simply saved the data uri as files on local fs and then use easy-pdf-merge to combine them and create a new combined.pdf and then read the file combined.pdf with 'base64' to get the data uri out and respond to client with correct data.  Works like a charm thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help you !

Comment: @DanielBallesteros can you refer your last answer?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620852/return-true-if-all-images-uploaded-to-firebase-storage

Comment: The question its deleted. Sorry